# Changing Default Controller Dyanmically in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, controller

I want to change my default controller in codeigniter is it possible? For guests I want to show different controller and for members another one

```
if($this->cuser->usercode()){
//loading default controller

$route['memebers_welcome'];

}else{

$route['guests_welcome'];

}
```

if its possible please advise otherwise I will have to use redirect function which I dont think is good practice.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a different perspective on the issue. Instead of trying to choose your controller based on whether a user is logged in, it's quite common to have your 'welcome' controller load a different view for a logged in or not logged in user.

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        # ...
        if ($this->cuser->usercode()) {
            $this->load->view('members_welcome');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('guests_welcome');
        }
    }
    # ...
}
```

Alternatively, if there are completely separate sets of logic that makes sense to make separate functions, you can easily call another controller method without needing to reload the page.

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        if ($this->cuser->usercode()) {
            $this->_members_welcome();
        } else {
            $this->_guests_welcome();
        } 
    }

    private function _members_welcome() {
        # ... do stuff for members
    }

    private function _guests_welcome() {
        # ... do stuff for guests
    }
}
```

It's much better to use this method that to actually direct users as you don't want to cause unecessary overhead and page loads.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. You can't because to change the controller, first you have to make sure whether the user is logged in or not and you can check this from within a controller and it's the easiest/proper way, AFAIK.

So just keep a default controller for both types of users and check the user type and redirect from that controller/page to a new controller/page if a user is not a member. you can check this in the constructor function of your default controller.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can it. And it is good way to reutilize code.

#### Create your own controllers

For example, if you want a controller for users and other ones to admins. Go to **application/core** folder and create them there:

```
class UserController extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if ( !is_logged() )
        {
            show_error('get out of here') // sorry, you are not logged
        }
        // load necessary libraries or helpers for logged user

    }
}
```

And if you want a controller for admin area, you can do it as:

```
class AdminController extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if ( !is_admin() )
        {
            show_error('only for admins') // sorry, you are not admin
        }
        // load necessary libraries or helpers for admin

    }
}
```

#### Load the controllers into the system

In order to get controllers be loaded as a part of CI system, you need to specify where reside them. So, at the end of **application/config/config.php** file put:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT))
        {
            include $file;
        }

        else if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $class . EXT))
        {
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Test your controllers

Now you are able to extends one of controllers above to use it according to you website area:

```
class Logout extends UserController{
```

or

```
class EditUser extends AdminController{
```